# Big oh notation running time

Tags: data-structures, big-o

How do you work this out? do you get c first which is the ratio of the two functions then with the ratio find the range of n ? how can you tell ? please explain i'm really lost, Thanks.

Example 1: Prove that running time T(n) = n^3 + 20n + 1 is O(n^3) 
Proof: by the Big-Oh definition,

T(n) is O(n^3) if T(n) ≤ c·n^3 for some n ≥ n0 .

Let us check this condition:

if n^3 + 20n + 1 ≤ c·n^3 then 1 + 20/n^2 + 1/n^3 <=c .

Therefore, 
the Big-Oh condition holds for n ≥ n0 = 1 and c ≥ 22 (= 1 + 20 + 1). Larger 
values of n0 result in smaller factors c (e.g., for n0 = 10 c ≥ 1.201 and so on) but in 
any case the above statement is valid.

Comment: Note that Big-O notation does not in fact tell you *the running time* of anything. It tells you how the running time of something *grows* when the number of items to process gets larger. What I mean is that having the Big-O notation of some algorithm will not in any way tell you how many seconds/time units that algorithm will take to process *x* elements. An in terms of Big-O notation, you only keep the biggest/most growing part of the expression, which is why Big-O notation for something that follows `n^3 + 2n^2` is `O(n^3)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the trick you're seeing is that you aren't thinking of LARGE numbers. Hence, let's take a counter example:

```
   T(n) = n^4 + n
```

and let's assume that we think it's `O(N^3)` instead of `O(N^4)`. What you could see is

```
   c = n + 1/n^2
```

which means that `c`, a constant, is actually `c(n)`, a function dependent upon `n`. Taking `N` to a really big number shows that no matter what, `c == c(n)`, a function of `n`, so it can't be `O(N^3)`.

What you want is in the limit as `N` goes to infinity, everything but a constant remains:

```
   c = 1 + 1/n^3
```

Now you can easily say, it is still `c(n)`! As `N` gets really, really big `1/n^3` goes to zero. Hence, with very large `N` in the case of declaring `T(n)` in `O(N^4)` time, `c == 1` or it is a constant!

Does that help?